# connecting geth to web3.js 1.0 via websockets or HTTP

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, ipc, websocket

I am building a minimal nodeJS application that should connect via web3.js to my geth node. I am following the [official web3.js1.0 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#id1) and I am using web3 1.0.0-beta.29.

I do manage to connect via IPC but both HTTP and websockets fail - in both cases I get the same output from my JS script as if there was no geth running at all. Any help would be appreciated.

**1) HTTP (not working)**

geth:

```
geth syncmode="fast" --cache=4096 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal"
```

index.js:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545'); // same output as with option below
// var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
console.log("Hello World");
```

output:

```
$ node index.js
Hello World
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

**2) websockets (not working)**

geth:

```
geth syncmode="fast" --cache=4096 --ws --wsport 8546 --wsorigins "*" console
```

index.js:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3("ws://localhost:8546"); // same output as with option below
// var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'));
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
console.log("Hello World");
```

output:

```
$ node index.js
Hello World
connection not open on send()
Error: connection not open
```

**3) IPC (works)**

geth: (same start as for HTTP)

geth syncmode="fast" --cache=4096 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal"

index.js:

```
var net = require('net');
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('/Users/sebastian/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc', net); // same output as with option below
// var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider('/Users/sebastian/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc', net));
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
console.log("Hello World");
```

output:

```
$ node index.js
Hello World
null [ '0x045a6A820FD596a4c1a49732af01E3EF1D6aEb8B' ]
```

Comment: You do not need --rpccorsdomain "*". It increases exposure of your RPC service, absolutely unnecessarily in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in geth command line: you miss double dash in front of syncmode. Not sure why, but it seems to prevent geth from launching HTTP RPC listener.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's required to declare the option `--wsorigins "*"` in the `geth` command in order to connect to the nodes via `websocket provider` or `http provider`.

In your case, you are missing double dash in front of `syncmode`, adding double dash or remove `syncmode` solves the problem.

Additional, according to the article https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options,

> --wsorigins value: Origins from which to accept websockets requests

Hope this help.

Comment: New param syntax `--ws.origin "*"`

Comment: Sorry, `--ws.origins "*"` !!!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using the `Geth 1.10.17-stable-25c9b49f`, [command line options](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) have changed a bit.

To enable the `HTTP` server, we now use the `--http` flag. And using the following code will achieve the same result now:
`geth --http --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api personal,eth,web3`

```js
// Node.js app
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
```